# NoSuchElementException: No line found when getting user input with scanner?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, binary-search

I'm trying to (just to make rating movies a little more easy to do; comparing the movie you're adding to every other movie on the list to know where it fits is hard to do and not very efficient) make a program that works sort of like a `binary insertion sort` to add a movie to a list of other movies, in the right order.  In the section that determines the spot in the list the movie should go, I am getting an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
    at Rater.binarySearch(Rater.java:32)
    at Rater.main(Rater.java:24)
```

I'm not sure what's causing this.  The code is below:

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Rater 
{ 
  public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception 
  { 
      File file = new File("E:\\topmovies.txt"); 

      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); 

      String st; 
      ArrayList<String> movList = new ArrayList<String>();
      while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
        movList.add(st);
      } 
      br.close();
      while(true) {
          System.out.println("Enter a movie to add.");
          Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
          String userName = myObj.nextLine(); 
          myObj.close();
          int index = binarySearch(movList, userName, 0, movList.size()-1);
          movList.add(index, userName);
      }
  }

  static int binarySearch(ArrayList<String> a, String item, int low, int high) 
  { 
      Scanner myObj3 = new Scanner(System.in);
      if (high <= low) { 
          System.out.println("Did you like " + item + " more than " + a.get(low) + "?");
          String answer2 = myObj3.nextLine().toLowerCase(); 
          myObj3.close();
          if(answer2.equals("yes")) {
              return low + 1;
          }
          return low;
      }

      int mid = (low + high)/2; 

      if(item == a.get(mid)) {
          myObj3.close();
          return mid+1; 
      }

      System.out.println("Did you like " + item + " more than " + a.get(mid) + "?");
      String answer2 = "";
      if(myObj3.hasNextLine()){
          answer2 = myObj3.nextLine().toLowerCase(); 
      }
      myObj3.close();
      if(answer2.equals("yes")) { 
          return binarySearch(a, item, mid+1, high); 
      }
      return binarySearch(a, item, low, mid-1); 
  } 
}
```

Please ignore the bad naming conventions, and the fact that this may not yet do what it's supposed to do.  Right now I'm just trying to fix this scanner not working.

Comment: Can you try creating only one Scanner (and passing it around) ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what your end goal is, but I was able to solve your error by doing this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Rater
{
    static Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
    {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\hparekh\\OneDrive - Visa Inc\\Documents\\test.txt");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        String st;
        ArrayList<String> movList = new ArrayList<String>();
        while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
            movList.add(st);
        }
        br.close();
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Enter a movie to add.");
            String userName = myObj.nextLine();
            int index = binarySearch(movList, userName, 0, movList.size()-1);
            movList.add(index, userName);
        }
    }

    static int binarySearch(ArrayList<String> a, String item, int low, int high)
    {
        if (high <= low) {
            System.out.println("Did you like " + item + " more than " + a.get(low) + "?");
            String answer2 = myObj.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            if(answer2.equals("yes")) {
                return low + 1;
            }
            return low;
        }

        int mid = (low + high)/2;

        if(item == a.get(mid)) {
            return mid+1;
        }

        System.out.println("Did you like " + item + " more than " + a.get(mid) + "?");
        String answer2 = "";
        if(myObj.hasNextLine()){
            answer2 = myObj.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        }
        if(answer2.equals("yes")) {
            return binarySearch(a, item, mid+1, high);
        }
        return binarySearch(a, item, low, mid-1);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.